# Problem involving Derivative and Antiderivative operators in Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a homework problem from Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*.

Let *F* be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T$, $D$ be the transformations of $F[x]$ defined by
$$\begin{align} T\left(\sum_{i=0}^n{c_ix^i}\right) &=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{c_i}{i+1}x^{i+1} \\
D\left(\sum_{i=0}^n{c_ix^i}\right) &=\sum_{i=1}^nic_ix^{i-1} \end{align}$$
These look like the anti-derivative and derivative operators.  I am to show that $DT=I$ but $TD\neq I$.  So,
$$DT\left(\sum_{i=0}^n{c_ix^i}\right)=D\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{c_i}{i+1}x^{i+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n{(i+1)}\frac{c_i}{i+1}x^{i+1-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n{c_ix^i}.$$
It is close, but my index is off by 1, and so they can't be equal since I am missing my constant term.

What am I missing? Do I need to rewrite the argument in the derivative operator before I operate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $D$ operator drops the constant term, not the term indexed by $0$. Note that dropping the constant term is well defined, but usually we allow a series to be re indexed and considered the same, which certainly makes sense when the series converges for example, so an operator that dropped the term indexed by zero would not be well-defined.

Edit: To be more explicit, I think you mistake is that you misunderstand the definition in the text.  The definition does not say to drop the term in the series that is indexed by $0$, but rather that the constant term goes away.  So, in the series

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{c_i}{i+1} x^{i+1}
$$

The term indexed by $0$ is $c_0x^1$, and we can't just drop it.  IN particular, we could rewrite this sum as

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{c_{i-1}}{i} x^i
$$

Then maybe it's more clear that applying $D$ to this series we get

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}c_{i-1}x^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_ix^i
$$

Comment: But there is no constant term on the RHS when my bounds are 1 and n,.  In other words, if DT were the identity operator then I should get back $c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n$, right?  I'm getting back $c_1x+...+c_nx^n$?

Comment: im not sure which right hand side you mean, but the error is $D\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{c_i}{i+1}x^{i+1}\right) \neq \sum_{i=1}^{n}(i+1)\frac{c_i}{i+1}x^{i+1-1}$ because the series being operated on left hand side has constant term zero and linear term $c_0x$ but you've dropped the linear term.

Comment: But what you have should be equal because that is the definition of the operator according to the authors.

Comment: I'll expand my answer, give me a minute

Comment: Thank you.  I think I get what you are saying and I think I see my error, but I'm still having trouble fixing it.

Comment: Now I get it.  Thank you!