# On an algebra $F[x]$, defining operators $T,D$ as integration, differentiation, respectively, show that $DT = I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am finding difficulty in constructing a proof as requested in the following:

Let $F$ be a subfield of the complex numbers and let $T$, $D$ be the transformations on $F[x]$ defined by

$$ T \left( \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i \right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i}{1+i} x^{i+1}$$

and

$$ D \left( \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n i c_i x^{i-1}.$$

I am asked to show that $DT = I$, where $I$ is the identity. (Please note the indices on the above sums.)

Clearly, $T$ and $D$ correspond to integration and differentiation, respectively. I felt that this proof should be straightforward, but I'm not able to get it quite right. Here is what I have:

$$
\begin{align}
(DT)\left(\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i \right) &= D \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{c_i}{1+i} x^{i+1} \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n c_i x^i
\end{align}
$$

This uses the definitions of the operators, as given. However, the lower index in the last sum is $i= 1$, which is one higher than the $i=0$ in the original sum that $DT$ was applied to; in loose wording, the constants are gone (i.e., we integrated and then differentiated but the constants in the original expression are now gone). The value of this lower bound makes sense because of the $c^{i-1}$ term; if $i$ can be zero, we would have $x^{-1}$, which is not defined in this contact. To me, resolving this seems impossible, based on the definition of the operator $D$ as given in the text; no matter what the train of logic is, I do not see a way for the lower bound of the final index to be zero, which seems to me to be necessary in order to conclude that $DT =I$.

I do not see how to get around this in order to complete this proof. Where is my error?

---

A comment on my question suggests that we can simply index the aforementioned sum from $i=0$ since $ic_ix^{i-1}$ can be taken to have value zero for $i = 0$. However, the second part of this exercise asks to show that $TD \neq I$, which does seem to rely on the indices of the sums in the given definitions. Where is the subtlety here?

---

This is Exercise 9 in Section 3.7 of *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: You may let the $\Sigma$ in the definition of $D$ run from $i=0$ without harm

Comment: In the definition of $D$ we have an $x^{i-1}$ term. If $i$ can take on the value of $0$, we would have $x^{-1}$, which is not defined in this context. Am I wrong?

Comment: But the $i$ in the coefficient will make the term disappear anyway.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024291/derivative-and-antiderivative-operators-in-hoffman-kunze

Comment: Thank you. Am I wrong to suggest that the expression is not well defined for $i = 0$ (which would give $x^{-1})$, regardless of the presence of a zero coefficient? Would you interpret that a reindexing of the given sums is part of this exercise?

Comment: To expound (and as I edited my original post to say), the second part of this exercise asks to show that $TD \neq I$, and this does seem to rely on the definition of the operators as given. Is there a subtlety here?